# What happens under the hood when you call `npm run` to run a NPM script?

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, git-bash

I would like to know more about how NPM scripts work.

For example:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "set NODE_ENV=production&& webpack --config webpack.config.js",
}
```

When I execute `npm run build`:

What happens? I know a `Node` process will be initiated somewhere and `webpack` binary file will be called, right? But what are the steps before that? Does that depend whether I'm on Windows, Linux, `PowerShell` or `Git bash`? How does that process relate to the OS and the CMD/CLI that is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `npm` source code helpfully has the whole `run-script` functionality separated into its own module and repository so you can [review the source code](https://github.com/npm/run-script) if [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts) does not answer your questions.

Speaking of your questions:

> I know a Node process will be initiated somewhere and webpack binary file will be called, right?

The `webpack` executable will be run. And since `webpack` is a Node.js script, it will be run with `node`.

If, however, your "build" value consisted of shell/CLI commands, those commands would be run. Node.js is not necessarily invoked.

> But what are the steps before that?

The "steps before that" include certain lifecycle scripts that might also be defined. In particular, if there is a "prebuild" script, it will run before the "build" script.

> Does that depend whether I'm on Windows, Linux, PowerShell or Git bash? How does that process relate to the OS and the CMD/CLI that is being used?

`npm` (and `node`) make efforts to make Windows and Linux experiences comparable. Differences occur for sure, but without more details, I'm not sure I'd want to speculate about what specifics might be of interest to you beyond that.

Powershell and GitBash: Again, `npm` will make efforts to smooth out differences, but I'm sure they come up. One thing to be aware of is that your `PATH` (and other environment variables) might be set differently and that may affect behavior. (It may especially impact which version of `node` gets executed, if you have more than one version installed.)

I am not a Windows expert, but I have seen a lot of `npm` scripts that assume a UNIX-like environment. So, if given the choice and all else being equal (which it never is), a bash-like environment is probably going to be a bit smoother.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if I got it right. Is this the correct sequence? 1 - The CLI that you are in (PowerShell, Bash, whatever) needs to be aware of the path for the `npm` command. That probably was set when you installed Node, correct? 2 - Node will evaluate the script and decide what to do? Either spin up a Node process or run shell/CLI commands? If there are shell/CLI commands, what will be used to run those commands?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was something like this:

When you call `npm run`, npm will initiate a shell to run those instructions.

And which shell npm will use is defined in your npm settings.

You can see your npm config by running:

```
>>> npm config ls
```

[image]

In the example above, npm will run the script on `git-bash`.

You can change the npm shell by calling:

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```